# Changing background image of uibutton makes frame huge

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am programmatically changing the background of a uibutton with this code:

```
firstButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "drinks-sub-first"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

trouble is the button is no longer constrained by the constraints I set up in the .xib file and takes up the entire screen now. What am I doing wrong? How can I make the button stay the same size as it was before changing the background image?

also I tried this approach already

```
var frame = firstButton.frame
firstButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "drinks-sub-first"), forState: UIControlState.Normal) //tried setBackgroundImage function as well
firstButton.frame = frame
```

Comment: You probably need to change the content mode of your button's image

Comment: What constraints do you have on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on the constraints that you've set for the button. You should have the width and height set to "less than or equal" to whatever value you want; you might have them set to "greater than or equal". Or if you want them the same width and height no matter what, then set the constraints to "equal" the value.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the background image with the method `setImage()`. That method sets the accessory image on a UIButton.

To set the background image for a button use the method:

`setBackgroundImage(image: UIImage?, forState state: UIControlState)`

Comment: actually this was something I had changed I tried this already as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newb, but I've gotten so much help here I feel compelled to help anytime I get an inkling I can.  Check out this quick tutorial on working with button background images: http://www.raywenderlich.com/78264/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-5

From the tutorial:

You may notice your button looks a little bit squished at this point. This is because you have hardcoded width and height constraints that are smaller than the image itself.  (in your case, it's the opposite I guess, but still ...)

Luckily, there is an easy way to fix this. All views have something called an intrinsic content size, which you can think of as an automatic constraint that is set to the size of the element being presented. In the case of an image, it will be the size of the image itself.

So rather than having hardcoded width and height constraints, you can rely on the intrinsic content size of the image to size the image view appropriately.

Comment: yeh I used an adaptive layout and set the width height using a percentage of the total views height

Comment: I wondered ... when you said programmatically  ... but I'm desperate to give something back to this site and help others, so I thought I'd give it a shot.  May the force be with you.